# Does a new() EF Context in the constructor of a controller properly handle the disposal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

ASP.NET website [recommends implementing Disposable on my repository](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) which affects my datacontext.

Is it sufficient for me to initialize the datacontext here, and casually let ASP.NET dispose of the resources?

Under what conditions will it not get called?  I am debugging frequently (ending the debug session mid page) and noticed that I needed to reboot to reclaim some memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC will not dispose any `IDisposable` instances you create. You are in-charge of disposing them. You can either over ride `Dispose` method of the controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
      {
          //dispose them here
      }
}
```

Or use a Dependency Injection/IoC framework to control the lifetime of the `IDisposable` instances. Many DI/IoC frameworks will automatically call the `Dispose` method if the framework created those instances.